# Vertices of Six Sided Polygons from Planar Points Coordinates?

Tags: math, grid, coordinates, connectivity, cells

Is there a way to draw six-sided polygons from a list of random planar points' coordinates or index, the points being the polygons' vertices ?

Many thanks,

Arthur

Comment: "Point Coordinate" representing "the logical cell position" or...?

Comment: The points coordinate is the only information I have and the output of the algorithm should be hexagonal or rectangular cells. The points have a random arrangement therefore the cells could vary in sizes...Any help would be great!

Comment: Your problem is underspecified. What are the points supposed to represent? Cell centroids, vertices or something else?

Comment: The vertices of the cells. I understand that some of these points might be ignored to generate a hexagonal grid whereas a rectangular grid could take every points into account? I got these points by intersecting a series of horizontal and vertical lines...

Comment: you mean you have a bunch of points in the plane, and you want to overlay a hexagonal or rectangular grid so that all the points are on grid vertices?

Comment: I do have a bunch of random points in a plane and would like to use them as vertices to connect six edges cells. Maybe the term hexagonal grid is wrong here as I don't mind difference in the edges length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved this with help from Jon Mirtschin (Geometry Gym) is to take a hexagonal grid code and identify the closest points from my random set of points to this grid. This sorts out the points index in the same order as the grid.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the points as the control points of a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). This will yield irregular convex polygons, not hexagons or rectangles. But I don't know if that's even possible with random points.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcelo, I am used to defining voronoi cells by their centers not control points. How could this achievable? By rectangular and hexagonal cells I meant the number of edges not the actual angles of hexagons and rectangles. Maybe there is a way to define the number of neighbours in a delauney triangulation and get a specific cell with four or six edges?